# Laravel 5.2 - regra de validação não funciona

Tags: laravel-5, validação

Preciso fazer uma validação de um campo de CEP, más as seguintes tentativas não funcionan:

```
$rules= ['cep'  => 'required|numeric|size:8'];
ou
$rules= ['cep'  => 'required|numeric|min:8'];
ou
$rules= ['cep'  => 'numeric|size:8'];
```

As seguintes validações funcionan:

```
$rules= ['cep'  => 'required|numeric'];
ou
$rules= ['cep'  => 'required|size:8'];
```

Alguém tem idéia do motivo de não funcionar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*CEP* pode começar com **0**, exemplo **01415000**, então não pode ter `numeric` e o `size:8` juntos e nunca vai ter oito números se começar com **0**.

Então o ideal para validação seria com [**digits**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-digits):***8***: essa validação funciona verificando se todos são números e se a quantidade de número é igual a 8 inclusive o 0.

```
$rules = ['cep'  => 'required|digits:8'];
```

Se por ventura quiser criar um validação com um código própria siga o exemplo abaixo:

***Registrando um validação:***

```
Validator::extend('cep', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    return mb_strlen($value) === 8 && preg_match('/^(\d){8}$/', $value)
});
```

---

```
$rules= ['cep'  => 'required|cep'];
```

Nesse aspecto vai funcionar a validação a sua maneira. Nesse [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#available-validation-rules), são as validações que o [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) possui para versão 5.2 e 5.3 até o momento.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, @virgilio-novic ! Mas, independente de ser o caso de validação de CEP, se eu fizer a mesma validação de um campo que, por exemplo, deveria ser preenchido, numérico e ter 3 digitos, a regra $rules= ['campox'  => 'required|numeric|size:3'] ainda não funciona.

Comment: @JulioAlves eu fiz a edição e agora faça o teste com `digits:8`, porque, nesse digits ele precisa ser um número com uma quantidade exata de números, inclusive o 0 a esquerda.

Comment: Agora sim, @VirgilioNovic! Resolveu o problema. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @JulioAlves bacana que bom que foi solucionado.