# Laravel 5.8 - Criar validações personalizadas para utilizar em um FormRequest?

Tags: php, laravel

Gostaria de criar algumas validações personalizadas e chama-las dentro do `FormRequest` conforme imagem:

[image: Regras do FormRequest]

Comment: Qual validação? seja mais especifico

Comment: no caso seria qualquer tipo de validação que não venha por padrão no Laravel. Por exemplo validar um "CPF" , validar se em determinado campo veio alguma palavra especifica. Gostaria de criar vários tipos de validações e poder chama-los diretamente do FormRequest, assim como chamo as validações nativas do Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para criar uma validação dessa forma crie uma classe para validar esse processo, que tenha  a seguinte código:

**Verificar** ***Cnpj***:

```
<?php namespace App\Utils;


class CnpjValidation
{
    public function validate($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
    {
        return $this->isValidate($attribute, $value);
    }

    protected function isValidate($attribute, $value)
    {
        $c = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $value);
        $b = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2];
        if (strlen($c) != 14) {
            return false;
        }
        elseif (preg_match("/^{$c[0]}{14}$/", $c) > 0) {
            return false;
        }
        for ($i = 0, $n = 0; $i < 12; $n += $c[$i] * $b[++$i]);
        if ($c[12] != ((($n %= 11) < 2) ? 0 : 11 - $n)) {
            return false;
        }
        for ($i = 0, $n = 0; $i <= 12; $n += $c[$i] * $b[$i++]);
        if ($c[13] != ((($n %= 11) < 2) ? 0 : 11 - $n)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Verificar** ***Cpf***

```
<?php namespace App\Utils;

class CpfValidation
{
    public function validate($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
    {
        return $this->isValidate($attribute, $value);
    }

    protected function isValidate($attribute, $value)
    {
        $c = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $value);
        if (strlen($c) != 11 || preg_match("/^{$c[0]}{11}$/", $c)) {
            return false;
        }
        for ($s = 10, $n = 0, $i = 0; $s >= 2; $n += $c[$i++] * $s--);
        if ($c[9] != ((($n %= 11) < 2) ? 0 : 11 - $n)) {
            return false;
        }
        for ($s = 11, $n = 0, $i = 0; $s >= 2; $n += $c[$i++] * $s--);
        if ($c[10] != ((($n %= 11) < 2) ? 0 : 11 - $n)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

nessas duas classes tem duas validações que geralmente não tem no pacote de validações padrões e precisam coexistir.

Para registrar essas duas classes abra o caminho `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` e dentro do método dessa classe `boot` coloque essas duas linhas:

```
/*Validations*/
Validator::extend('cpf', '\App\Utils\CpfValidation@validate');
Validator::extend('cnpj', '\App\Utils\CnpjValidation@validate');
```

e com isso nas classes `FormRequest` chame o alias `cpf` e `cnpj` como exemplo abaixo:

```
$rules = [
    'input_cnpj' => 'required|cnpj',
    ....
```

Se a validação for pequena que não sofra muita alteração nesse método `boot` pode ser criado uma função também dessa forma:

```
Validator::extend('cep', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) 
{
    return mb_strlen($value) === 8 && preg_match('/^(\d){8}$/', $value)
});
```

essa validação é para `cep` e pode também ser usado diretamente assim.

<sup>***Referencias.***</sup>

- [Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation)
- [Editar registro antes de passar por regra de validação no Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167930/editar-registro-antes-de-passar-por-regra-de-valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-laravel)
- [Validação no Laravel 5 em campos do tipo array?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/158381/valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-laravel-5-em-campos-do-tipo-array/158712#158712)
- [Laravel 5.2 - regra de validação não funciona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151203/laravel-5-2-regra-de-valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-n%C3%A3o-funciona/151406#151406)
- [Validação no Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228534/valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-laravel/228671#228671)